# How to enumerate activities I did

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses, lists

I'm writing a CV and in one section I'd like to enumerate the activities I did. Should I write

- I proved ...
- I participated ...
- I mentored ...
  ...

or

- Proved ...
- Participated ...
- Mentored ...
  ...

or

- Prove ...
- Participate ...
- Mentor ...
  ...

or any other better form for the verbs?

Comment: These are stylistic questions about a specialized field (resume writing), not within the scope of this site. There are numerous approaches, mostly controlled by the professional arena in which you are applying, as well as local custom.

Comment: The third version is definitely wrong, though. You did these activities in the past, so you should use the past tense. If you're still doing them, you would use `Proving`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second style is most common in CVs.

While English does not typically allow [pronoun dropping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language), CVs are a special case, since "I" is implied everywhere.  Therefore, most CVs omit "I" from every sentence.

The third style is inappropriate, as it looks like either present tense or an imperative.

Comment: What if the activity is also presently happening?  Then `ed` is not applicable?

Comment: At the risk of veering off-topic for EL&U… I suggest that you treat all items as accomplishments, i.e. in the past tense. In any case, you want your future employer to think of achievements in your current job as done deeds, even if they are work in progress.